# How to fit rectangles in a given area?

Tags: algorithm, vba, rectangles, packing

I have a given area (eg. the circle, but it can equally be a triangle). I need to find the best values for Xi and Yi so that these rectangles cover as much as possible of this area. I have a given step for the increment of Yi.

I have to do this at VBA (Excel) where I am not that experienced. Making all the possible combinations with a for loop is not efficient at all and may take hours.

I would need some advice on how to optimize this problem.

I have seen similar packing problems but in most of them the size of the rectangles is already known.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at a related question with Excel VBA code in the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606002/number-of-squares-in-a-circle/606123#606123

Comment: What is your "given step for the increment of `Yi`"?

Comment: My code is structured like this: 

For a minimum_Y to a maximum_Y with a given_step

Do Y4=minimum_Y
   Y3=Y4+given_step etc.  

Here the maximum_Y is defined by the radius for example. It can't be bigger than the circle's radius

Comment: How does x relate to y? Proportionally? Are there are always eight rectangles? What do you mean by optimize? Reduce waste? Maximize y?

Comment: `Y4=min(Y3)=Y4+step`? What do you mean? How can `Y4=Y4+step`?

Comment: Those are two difference lines `Y4=minimum_Y` and `Y3=Y4+step`

Comment: There are always 8 rectangles. Optimisation for my problem should be to use as much as possible of the given area of the circle. Also as you can see it is a symmetrical problem so I can use only the half circle

Answer (score 0):

Having a known increment for the `Yi` means that knowing `Y1` you can find all other `Yi`, and subsequently all `Xi` (from the circle equation `(Sum Xi)^2 + Yi^2/4 = R^2`). And from these, the covered area.

This establishes a relation between Y1 and the objective function. First plot it so see how the maxima(s) look like (piecewise smooth but discontinuous). Then... call the team again.

For ease of work in Excel, you can proceed with a fixed number of rectangles and set a zero `Xi` for those that get out of the circle.